# How to handle failures using MySQLi?

Tags: php, error-handling, mysqli

I am currently developing a website which uses [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for the database access. Currently the code that performs a database query looks something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT height, color FROM llamas WHERE name = ?";
if(!$stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
   // Error handling here.
}
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($height, $color);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

The return values for most of these calls return `FALSE` to indicate a problem. From the PHP docs:

> Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure.

If I attempt to check all of these function calls for false, I get something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT height, color FROM llamas WHERE name = ?";
if(!$stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
   // Error handling here.
}
if(!$stmt->bind_param("s", $name)) {
    // Error handling here.
}
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    // Error handling here.
}
if(!$stmt->store_result()) {
    // Error handling here.
}
if(!$stmt->bind_result($height, $color)) {
    // Error handling here.
}
if(!$stmt->fetch()) {
    // Error handling here.
}
if(!$stmt->close()) {
    // Error handling here.
}
```

**My question is:** Which of these function calls do I actually need to check for a return value of `FALSE`? And is there a tidy way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `PDO` and `try` - `catch`

```
try {
    // your code here                   
} catch(PDOException $e){
    error_log('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Edit: Here is the MySQLi version

```
try {

} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {

}
```

Comment: That does look like a nice solution, but unfortunately the website has already been built on MySQLi and it would take quite a bit of effort to convert it to PDO.

Comment: @DanielGibbs I have added the MySQLi version

Comment: Do the above methods actually throw a `mysql_sql_exception`? I can't see anything in the documentation about them doing so.